# raspistill timelapse black photos noir camera

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspistill

I have a script with line:

```
   raspistill -n -w 1296 -h 972 -t 4000 -e jpg -q 40 -o %s -tl 200 -x
```

Script generates about 8 photos but when it's dark all photos are black except one 6th or 7th. 
Is there a better way to generate series of photos in short period of time of which more will be useful in poor light?

Comment: Maybe add `-ex night`?

Comment: Or try increasing the ISO, with `-ISO 800`?